# How can I ssh to my private ec2 instance using circleci?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh, circleci

I have my application deployed on a private ec2 instance in a private subnet. I have also created a public subnet through which any of my team members can ssh into the private instance. So the same thing I want to do with circle ci first I am making a connection of circleci to a public instance and within that instance it is ssh into a private instance.
I have tested the connect locally it is working well, the security group, subnets, VPC everything is cool. but the problem is that circle ci is unable to ssh into the private instance but good in a public instance.
I have also edited ~/.ssh/hosts in a public subnet to add an entry to private instance Also I have added the circleci key to both instances.

This is the bash script that circleci is running while deployment.

```
command: bash ./aws_deploy.sh "$CIRCLE_BRANCH" "$SSH_EC2_IP" "$BETA_EC2_IP"

./aws_deploy.sh

ssh -A -tt -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $2"
ssh -i sultan-key.pem $3'
cd /var/www/linkedunion-development/
git fetch --all
git checkout -B $1 origin/$1
docker-compose down -v
docker system prune --all --force
docker stop $(docker ps -q)
docker rm $(docker ps -aq)
docker rmi $(docker images -q)
git pull
./git_fetch.sh'"
```

This is the error circle ci is throwing

> Warning: Permanently added '54.215.128.217' (ECDSA) to the list of
> known hosts. ssh: Could not resolve hostname 10.0.20.108 cd
> /var/www/linkedunion-development/ git fetch --all git checkout -b
> nt-migrate-prestagi: Name or service not known Connection to
> 54.215.128.217 closed.
>
> Exited with code exit status 255

Please help!

Comment: Without knowing a lot about your VPC, `Could not resolve hostname 10.0.20.108` seems like the most important detail.

Comment: I think your problem is related to your use of quotes. If I simplify your script:

cat script.sh 
#!/bin/bash
ssh -A -tt -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $1"
ssh -i sultan-key.pem $2'"

And then run it, I get a similar error: ./script.sh batman.com robin.com
ssh: Could not resolve hostname batman.com

If I modify your script to add a space after the hostname:
cat script.sh 
#!/bin/bash
ssh -A -tt -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $1 "
ssh -i sultan-key.pem $2'"

It resolves the hostname correctly. You'll likely have an issue with the single quote in use as well.

Comment: Yeah You are right It was solved already. The problem was in quotes.